# "It can't be helped": しようがない , し方ない , しかない

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

「しょうがない」/「しようがない」

「しかない」

「仕方がない」

What are the subtle differences in usage of the above three ways for saying "there's no way" or "it cant be helped"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

仕方がない may imply less than ideal circumstances where only limited options exist. It could be used to describe a hopeless or grim scenario.

```
Example Sentences from Jisho.org:

行くより他に仕方がないんだ。
We have no choice but to go.

そこへ行っても仕方がない。
It is no use going there.

彼にしたがうより他に仕方がない。
I cannot do otherwise than obey him.
```

しょうがない bears a similar meaning to 仕方がない.
Both phrases literally mean “there’s no way”. This is more of a
conversational expression while 仕方がない is the formal one.

```
Example Sentences from Jisho.org:

あの子はしょうがない子だ。
That child is impossible.

冷たいものを飲みたくてしょうがない。
I am dying for a cold drink.

男の子のいたずらはしょうがない。
Boys will be boys.
```

しかない just means “only”.
The sentences below would both literally mean “Among the children, there’s only one girl”.

```
女の子は１人しかいない。
(ない is changed to いない since were talking about person)
女の子は１人だけだ
https://hinative.com/ja/questions/6212497 for the example
```